# ! Improper \halign inside $$'s

Tags: errors, align

I know this is not a minimal example, but I have to have this much code, in order to create my error. I had this error already several times and I cannot get rid of it?! I don't know where the problem is. Something is not correct with align and footnotes, at least this seems to be the reason for me?

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 
        12pt,                               
        bibliography=totoc,     
        index=totoc,    
        abstracton,     
        headsepline,    
        ]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{latexsym}           
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}   
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}   
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{subfig}     
\usepackage{float}      
\usepackage{graphicx}       
\usepackage{rotating}   
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{eurosym,bm,amsmath,amssymb,verbatim}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage [round,authoryear] {natbib}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx,eso-pic,lipsum}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tocstyle}
\usetocstyle{allwithdot} 
\usepackage[bookmarksopen,hyperfootnotes=false,pdftitle=test, pdfauthor=test,pdfsubject=test]{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{listings} 
\usepackage{remreset} 
\makeatletter
\@removefromreset{footnote}{chapter}
\makeatother
\usepackage{dblfnote} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\KOMAoption{footnotes}{multiple} 
\usepackage[top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
 \usepackage{cleveref} 


\definecolor{headercolor}{rgb}{0,0,0}
\definecolor{white2}{rgb}{255,255,255}



\begin{document}                    



\begin{titlepage}
test

\end{titlepage}

\onehalfspacing 

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  %% Clear all headers and footers
  \fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\hspace{5.5mm}\textcolor{white2}{\leftmark}\\ \text{ }\textcolor{white2}{\hspace{0.4cm}\rightmark}\hfill\textcolor{white2}{}\hspace{2mm}}
\renewcommand{\headrule}{\vspace{-\headheight}\textcolor{white2}{\vrule height \headheight width 2pt\relax\rule{\textwidth}{2pt}\vrule height \headheight width 2pt\relax}}
\fancyfoot[C]{-\thepage -}
}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
%\renewcommand{\chaptername}{}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
\markboth{\MakeUppercase{\thechapter. \hspace{1.5mm} \  #1}}{}}


\fancyhead[L]{\hspace{5.5mm}\textcolor{headercolor}{\leftmark}\\ \text{ }\textcolor{headercolor}{\hspace{0.4cm}\rightmark}\hfill\textcolor{headercolor}{}\hspace{2mm}}
\renewcommand{\headrule}{\vspace{-\headheight}\textcolor{headercolor}{\vrule height \headheight width 2pt\relax\rule{\textwidth}{2pt}\vrule height \headheight width 2pt\relax}}
\fancyfoot[C]{-\thepage -}

\begin{appendix}
\clearpage
\chapter{Appendix}


\subsection[Text]{Text}
\label{parameterestimation}
text texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext text\footnote{\citep[pp. 7-8]{Author1:1993}}. text texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext text\footnote{\citep[para. 4]{Author2:2002}}.

\subsubsection[Textn]{Text}
text texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext text\footnote{\citep[para. 4] {Hazewinkel:2002}}.
\paragraph{ML}\footnote{Text \citep[p. 12-13]{A:2006}}
text texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext text
\begin{align*}
54=54
\end{align*}
and the log likelihood by
\begin{align*}
54=54
\end{align*}
vtext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext text
\begin{align*}
54=54
\end{align*}
text texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext text\footnote{\citep[p. 3] {Author1:2006} text texttext text}. text texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext text\footnote{\citep[para. Details] {Author2}}. text texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext text\footnote{\citep[para. Details] {RDocumentationoptim}} text texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext text\footnote{\citep[para. Details] {RDocumentationfitdistr}}). \\ \newline
text texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext text\footnote{\citep[p. 53] {Ruppert:2004}}:
\begin{align*}
54 = 45
\end{align*}
text texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext texttext text\footnote{\citep[p. 7] {Steenbergen:2006}}:

  \end{appendix}



\clearpage
\fancyhead[L]{\hspace{4mm}\textcolor{headercolor}{}\text{ }\textcolor{headercolor}{\rightmark}\hfill\textcolor{headercolor}{}\hspace{2mm}}
\renewcommand{\headrule}{\vspace{-\headheight}\textcolor{headercolor}{\vrule height \headheight width 2pt\relax\rule{\textwidth}{2pt}\vrule height \headheight width 2pt\relax}}
\fancyfoot[C]{-\thepage -}

\end{document}
```

I get the error:

! Improper \halign inside $$'s.
 \halign

This is NOT due to a specific align environment, e.g. a typo error in an align environment, I have this problem throughout my complete thesis!

Comment: Please make a more reasonable minimal example. You clearly do not need to load all those packages, just removing tikz for example doesn't change the error message (and makes the example load in half the time) _before_ posting you should remove all packages that you can while still showing the error.

Comment: @lockstep I changed my original post, so I edited it, is this correct?

Comment: It's a good first step. Now you should a) delete the latter question b) use David Carlisle's advice to fix the former question.

Comment: It seems that commenting out `\usepackage{dblfnote}` solves the problem. That pacakge must conflict with something  else...

Comment: Also, leaving `\usepackage{dblfnote}` in, but commenting out `\footnote{Text \citep[p. 12-13]{A:2006}}` after `\paragraph{ML}` does not result in any error.

Comment: but I have this problem throughout my thesis and I need the footnotes and the package ? @Jubobs

Comment: I'm not saying you should eschew footnotes. My comments were meant to help more competent people than me to identify the cause of the error more quickly.